# get Error or stack trace from an app crash iOS

Tags: ios, swift

hi i want to know the error from a crash of my app in production, I figured out how to recognize if my app crashed during last time execution with crashlitycs but I want the error or the stack trace for send it to a service of my own with user feedback.
is there a way to obtain this error or stack trace with crashlytics, another package or native solution?
thanks

Comment: can you please share code of how you implemented crashlytics? what did you already tried?

Comment: You used `didCrashDuringPreviousExecution`, right? There is a `checkForUnsentReportsWithCompletion`, but to get the path of the `FIRCrashlyticsReport`, I don't think it's opened (you can see the hidden implementation, but it could change anytime...)